# Lazy Load error for the first time jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jquery-lazyload

MY AJAX REQUEST

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../WebService.asmx/getallimages",
    success: function (data) {
        //getting image srcs here
        for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            counter_xyz++;
            if(counter_xyz<10) {
                $("#holding_img_" + variable[i]).attr("src", variable[i].src);
            } else {
                $("#holding_img_" + variable[i]).attr("data-orig", variable[i].src);
            }
        }
        $("img.lazy").show().lazyload({
            data_attribute: "orig"                 
        }); 
    }
    error : function (data) {

    }
});
```

Have used tuupola..jquery_lazyload plugin .. 
Its working fine but first time when the user is opening the site .. its not getting applied
Lazy load is not working when all the cache is cleared. Not working in the sense the unscrolled part images are also loaded and are visible ..

I am not getting how to solve this error ..

**Note- Only first time this occurs..**

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {` .. What is `s`? what is `counter_xyz` ..? Can you create an online demo for this issue..?

Comment: first of all, you missed comma before `error` declaration

Comment: data shoud'nt be stringified: `data: {id: id},` should works. And what is `variable` and what do you do with `data`?

Comment: Comma is missing after success callback function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess comma is missing after success callback. Can you please check that.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the issue you are talking about... didn't investigate deeply enough to understand why it happens - but here is the Solution: load the scripts (JQuery and LazyLoad) without 
using the browser cache, the via injecting them into the page using "loadScript" function:

Tested under FF 32.0.3 (original issue in Chrome - due to a strict MIME type policy in lazyLoad script)

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JQUERY LazyLoad</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="holding_img_1" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_2" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_3" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_4" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_5" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_6" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_7" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_8" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_9" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_10" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_11" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_12" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_13" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_14" class="lazy"/>
    <img id="holding_img_15" class="lazy"/>
    <script>
        "use strict";
            function callback(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
            function loadScript(scriptSrc, jqueryLoaded) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.async = false;
                script.onload = function(){
                    if (jqueryLoaded) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            //data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/javascript; charset=UTF-8",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            url: "http://localhost:8080/images/?callback=callback",
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                //getting image srcs here
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    //counter_xyz++;
                                    //console.log(i);
                                    if(i<10) {
                                        $("#holding_img_" + i).attr("src", "http://localhost:8080/image/"+(i+1)+".jpg");
                                    } else {
                                        $("#holding_img_" + i).attr("data-orig","http://localhost:8080/image/"+(i+1)+".jpg");
                                    }
                                }
                                $("img.lazy").show().lazyload({
                                    data_attribute: "orig"                 
                                }); 
                            },
                            error : function (data) {

                            }
                        });  
                    }
                    else {
                        loadScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js", true);                    
                    }

                };
                script.src = scriptSrc;
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);           
            };
            loadScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you keep your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

This might help!

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

//Your ajax call..

});
```